How to understand the formula of carryout in addition from book Computer Organization and Design
I am reading chapter 8.5 ALU in Computer Organization and Design by David A Patterson and John L. Hennessy.
It first gets carryOut = b*carryIn + a*carryIn + a*b + a*b*carryIn (a and b are the two data inputs) by observing truth table (values of inputs when carryOut is 1)
My questions:

based on the rules of writing a two-level logic, shouldn't the formula be:
carryOut = ^a*b*carryIn + a*^b*carryIn + a*b*^carryIn + a*b*carryIn?

It then says



If a*b*carryIn is true, then all of the other three terms must also be true, so we can leave out this last term corresponding to the fourth line of the table. We can thus simplify the equation to
carryOut = b*carryIn + a*carryIn + a*b

How do you understand this?

What's the ISBN? What's the page number? I see something similar in an appendix. But it is obviously not chapter 8.5. So I'm curious exactly which edition this is.

I don't have your book, obviously, since my edition doesn't include a chapter 8.5 ALU. (I have the 4th and 5th editions, as well as the MIPS and RISC-V editions.) But, for example, the RISC-V version does have an appendix that I'll use for context.
First off, they are talking about a one-bit full-adder. The starting table is just this:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{CarryIn} & \text{CarryOut} & \text{Sum}\\ \hline      \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} \\ \hline
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
      1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
They write out that table in plain view.
From it, they pick out only the entries where CarryOut is 1:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{CarryIn} & \text{CarryOut} & \text{Sum}\\ \hline      \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} & \phantom{CarryOut} \\ \hline
      0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
From the above table, unoptimized, they say that:
$$\text{CarryOut}=\text{b}\cdot \text{CarryIn}+\text{a}\cdot \text{CarryIn}+\text{a}\cdot \text{b}+\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CarryIn}$$
That's just a plain and simple re-statement of the terms in the table. Four rows, four terms. Nothing could be simpler.
Then you ask:

based on the rules of writing a two-level logic, shouldn't the formula
be: carryOut = ^a*b*carryIn + a*^b*carryIn + a*b*^carryIn + a*b*carryIn?

Sure. You could write it out that way. And at times there is good reason to do so. But they didn't. Both of you are right. There is no conflict.
It's just two different ways of writing out exactly the same thing.
You then continue and ask:

It then says

If a*b*carryIn is true, then all of the other three terms must
also be true, so we can leave out this last term corresponding
to the fourth line of the table. We can thus simplify the
equation to carryOut = b*carryIn + a*carryIn + a*b


How do you understand this?

Easy. In fact, we can return to your own equation and simplify directly from it:
$$\begin{align*}
\text{COut}
&=
\overline{\text{a}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot\overline{\text{b}}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\overline{\text{CIn}} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn}
\\\\
&=
\overline{\text{a}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot\overline{\text{b}}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\overline{\text{CIn}} +
\left(\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn}\right)
\\\\
&=
\left(\overline{\text{a}}\cdot\text{b}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn}\right) +
\left(\text{a}\cdot\overline{\text{b}}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn}\right) +
\left(\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\overline{\text{CIn}} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\text{CIn}\right)
\\\\
&=
\left(\overline{\text{a}} + \text{a}\right)\cdot\text{b}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\left(\overline{\text{b}} + \text{b}\right)\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}\cdot\left(\overline{\text{CIn}} + \text{CIn}\right)
\\\\
&=
\text{b}\cdot \text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot\text{CIn} +
\text{a}\cdot \text{b}
\end{align*}$$
All I did was to replicate the same last term two more times, which changes nothing about the logic. And I used your equation, not theirs, to get their result from your own work.
I don't see a problem.

Thank you! This is what I needed! But could you tell me how you got carryOut = bcarryIn + acarryIn + ab + ab*carryIn from the truth table and where I can refer to for rules? Based on the book, for the input(a) that is 0, I need to put ^a in the terms.

@Bbbbbunn2023 It was just their own short-hand way of writing, looking over the shortened table. Look at the first entry. Then look down at the last entry. So $\text{a}\cdot\text{CarryIn}$ certainly works as those two table entries represent both cases needed. The same with the 2nd and 3rd rows, as they also similarly pair up with the 4th row. Can't you see that? Different people "see things" in differing ways. There's not only one way to think. You will need to be flexible enough to capture many ways of thinking, when reading.
